# iOS - UIImage + UILabel Constraint Conflict In UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview, nslayoutconstraint

In my app, I use a `UITableView` to display articles for the user. I have two types of `UITableViewCells`; one where an article doesn't have an image, and another where an article does have an image.

Both types of `UITableViewCells` have a title `UILabel` and a description `UILabel`. I have the `numberOfLines` of the title `UILabel` set to 0 since some article title can be long or short. This is the determining factor for the height of the `UITableViewCell`, since I'm using `UITableViewAutomaticDimension`.

It shows up perfectly in the case when an article has no image like so:

[image]

However, in the case where an article has an image, it's not working as I need it to. These are my `UIConstraints`:

Article Image View

- 0 pixels from the right, top, and bottom of the cell
- width constraint of 90 pixels

Title Label

- `numberOfLines` is 0
- 8 pixels from top and left of the cell
- 8 pixels from left of Article Image View

Description Label

- `numberOfLines` is 1
- 8 pixels from left of the cell
- 0 pixels from bottom of Title Label
- 8 pixels from left of Article Image View
- 8 pixels from bottom of the cell

It shows up like this:

[image]

This is very frustrating because my constraints look logical enough to be doing the job correctly.

I need my layout to look like how the Pocket app is doing it like so:

[image]

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong? Any help or advice would be appreciated. Thanks.

*****UPDATE*****

On the advice of @kirander, I have changed the content compression resistance priority of my `UIIMageView` to 250, which helped me get this result:

[image]

Is there any way to minimize the leftover space in the Title Label? I need the Title Label's height to be ONLY enough where all text fits, and not a pixel more.

Comment: I think you forget to add height constraint to the image view. Regarding to the screenshot the cell height is determined by the image.

Comment: I wasn't intending to give a height constraint to the image view because I need the image view to reach both the top and bottom of the cell at all times.

Comment: I understand. Then you should change content compression resistance priority in vertical axis so the label will have more priority than image.

Comment: @kirander Thank you very much for your advice! I've never touched those priority values before, and it has helped me significantly. Please check the update to my question because there is one more kink that I'm trying to work out.

Comment: The flip side of compression resistance is content hugging. Try increasing the content hugging priority of your Title Label.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the help. It turns out the the only thing I had to do was have the compression resistance of the image on 250 and the top of the Description Label 0 pixels from the bottom of the Title Label. Even though I said I had that in my question, it turns out that it wasn't there. Adding that fixed my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving this with the help of kirander and Mike Taverne. If you need a tight design similar to this, these were the constraints that got me what I wanted:

Article Image View

- 0 pixels from the right, top, and bottom of the cell
- width constraint of 90 pixels
- Content Compression Resistance Priority -> 250

Title Label

- numberOfLines is 0
- 8 pixels from top and left of the cell
- 8 pixels from left of Article Image View

Description Label

- numberOfLines is 1
- 8 pixels from left of the cell
- 0 pixels from bottom of Title Label (I mentioned this in the original question, but it turned out that I didn't have it...correcting that moved me toward my solution)
- 8 pixels from left of Article Image View
- 8 pixels from bottom of the cell

These constraints gave me the following tight design:

[image]